# Getting GMT as timezone instead of HST or PDT

Tags: java, android, timezone, simpledateformat

I am trying to display the current timestamp in log file with the TImeZone value. But I could observe that for 2 different users in same location, the timezone is printed differently.

For one user, it is displayed with HST as zone id and for other it is with GMT.

This problem with GMT is happening in Note 2 device and in Note 4 there is no problem.

Below is my code how I get the timestamp,

```
  try {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy z:hh:mm:ss a");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        currentTimeStamp = df.format(date);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Logger", "Error in getCurrentTimeStamp = " + e.getMessage(),e);
    }
```

What I am expecting is something like this,

```
  05/02/2015 HST:09:43:46 AM
```

But in Note 2 it always gives me,

```
  GMT-10:00:09:43:46 AM
```

I tried changing the phone's default timezone still no luck.

Can anybody please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HST is GMT-10 so its giving right time only the format is different.

> Greenwich Mean Time is 10 hours ahead of Hawaii Standard Time
>   7:04 PM Thursday, Hawaii Standard Time (HST) is
>   5:04 AM Friday, Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)

Use `Use DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy z:hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);` to get TimeZone name.

Comment: Yes, I got it.. But I want to print in HST only, not with respect to GMT. And this problem is happening in Note 2 device

Comment: Did you try the Localised version of the SimpleDateFormat?  public SimpleDateFormat (String template, Locale locale)

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: Use DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy z:hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);

Comment: You saved me!!! Cheers, it works. Can you update your answer so that I can accept. Thanks a lot, this was killing me